# Is a PayPal payment gateway required for a different integration for different countries?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to integrate payment gateway in my mobile application. I am going to launch my application for all region.One of my module requires payment integration. 
( my app is for online shopping)
I am thinking to use Paypal payment gateway for the same.

Is a PayPal payment gateway required for a different integration for different countries?

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no different integration. you will just have to differentiate local currency if you don't want to make it USD allover.

This [Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/) shows currently supported currency.